# Simple show hide functionality in the navigation bar options for login and logout in angular. I want to know why it's not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am unable to show the functionality after I logged in. I am not using session storage to get the user. I haven't done the logout functionality yet.

Html for navigation

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a *ngIf = "!invalidLogin" class="nav-link" routerLink="create">Add New Music</a>
                    {{!invalidLogin}}
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a *ngIf = "!invalidLogin" class="nav-link active" routerLink="list">Manage Items</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a *ngIf = "!invalidLogin" class="nav-link" routerLink="customerlist">Manage Customers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="addcustomer">SignUp</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a *ngIf = "invalidLogin" class="nav-link" routerLink="login">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I tried calling this.invalidLogin = true; in ngOnit(), but it is not working.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  invalidLogin: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.invalidLogin = true;
  }

}
```

Service class where I am trying to show/enable the functionality, though it is setting the property this.nav.invalidLogin = false, but it is not reflected in the Navigation Component. Here I am inject the NavigationComponent in the constructor. In the app.module.ts I have provided NavigationComponent in the providers.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  username: string = "divya@gmail.com";
  password: string = "divya123";




  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private nav: NavigationComponent, private router: Router) { }


  doLogin(user: Login){
    let temp = false;
    if((user.username === this.username) && (user.password === this.password)){
      this.nav.invalidLogin = false;
      temp = true;
    }else{
      temp = false;
      // this.message = "Invalid Credientials"
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

And finally it is the login component, where I am calling the service class which is used to set the  property this.nav.invalidLogin = false.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login: Login;
  message: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private nav : NavigationComponent, private custService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.login = new Login();
    
  }

  

  doLogin(user: Login){
    if(this.custService.doLogin(user)){
      console.log("Invalid user : ",this.nav.invalidLogin);
      this.router.navigate(["list"]);
    }else{
      this.message = "Invalid Credientials"
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use observables. This would allow for instant updating of your values.

I have simplified your code so that you only see the most needed parts (removing the classes and not needed imports in the classes).

**Here's what I would do for your HTML**

```html
<nav>
  <!-- This subscribes to your new class level observable value -->
  <!-- This is for the value being true - meaning the login is NOT invalid -->
  <ul *ngIf="!(invalidLogin | async)">
    <li>
      <a>Add New Music</a>
      - {{invalidLogin | async}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Manage Items</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Manage Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- This subscribes to your new class level observable value -->
  <!-- This is for the value being true - meaning the login IS invalid -->
  <ul *ngIf="(invalidLogin | async)">
    <li>
      <a>SignUp</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Here's what your component could look like**

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  // Setting up our class level variable to watch in the template.
  invalidLogin: Observable<boolean>;

  // Dependency injecting your service.
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // This is calling your service with BAD data.
    this.invalidLogin = this.customerService.doLogin({
      username: "divya@gmail.com",
      password: "not-matching"
    });
  }
}
```

**And finally your service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CustomerService {
  username: string = "divya@gmail.com";
  password: string = "divya123";

  // Typing your doLogin method to return an observable of boolean
  doLogin(user: any): Observable<boolean> {
    if (user.username === this.username && user.password === this.password) {
      // This returns an observable of true if they were to match
      return of(false);
    }
    // This returns an observable of false if they don't match
    return of(true);
  }
}
```

**Something I would suggest for *readability***:
Rename your components class level variable `invalidLogin` to `validLogin`. This will allow for your template to not have a double negative - which seems to confuse more people than not. Don't forget to flip those "!"'s in the template if you make this change! I would *highly* suggest this change.